# Implementing smallslider effect by jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've just started to learn JavaScript/jQuery this week. I am trying to implement this effect but in vain : http://blog.e8it.net/jquery-smallslider/

I am trying to figure how to display the effet by JavaScript. So I simply copy and past the code from internet to my html file.

I did import the smallslider.css, jquery.smallslider.js, and jquery-1.7.1.min.js.

Did I forget anything?

here's the .html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index3_style.css" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/smallslider.css" media="screen"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.smallslider.js"></script><D-4>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>         
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                 $('#photoslide').smallslider
                 ({
                     onImageStop:true,
                     switchEffect:'ease',
                     switchEase:'easeOutSine',
                     switchPath:'left',
                     switchMode:'hover', 
                     showText:true, 
                     textSwitch:2                  
                 });
            });
         </script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wraper" style="width:1020px; float:left;">
            <div id="header">
            </div>
            <div id="container" style="width:1020px; float=left;">
                <div id="photoslide">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="images/1.jpg" title="" alt="" /></li>
                        <li><img src="images/2.jpg" title="" alt="" /></li>
                        <li><img src="images/3.jpg" title="" alt="" /></li>
                        <li><img src="images/4.jpg" title="" alt="" /></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer" style="width:1020px; float=left;">
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

The smallslider.css:

```
$Document : smallslider$
$Created on : 2009-7-3, 11:56:24$
$Last Update : 2010-3-15, 11:20:22$
$Author:Sinrow$
$E-Mail : sinrow@yeah.net$
$Description : Stylesheet for smallslider, UTF-8 encoding $
```

The jquery.smallslider.js:

- SmallSilder JQuery plugin
- $http://lab.cnscene.com/smallslider/$
- $Document : jquery.smallslider.js$
- $Created on : 2009-7-3, 11:56:24$
- $Last Update: 2010-3-15, 14:40:16$
- $Author : Sinrow$
- $E-Mail: sinrow@yeah.net$
- $Description

Answer (score 0):

If that is all your smallslider.css and jquery.smallslider.js it will not work. Why don't you try something more well documented like this one? http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/imagestrip/imageslide-plugin.html

Comment: No it's not all of the code of course. I just wanted to state the information of the authur...